# Is it possible to set item "loadouts" to a hotkey in TF2?

Tags: team-fortress-2

With all the new items that have been added recently to Team Fortress 2, I find myself spending a lot more time at the item screen than I ever used to.  Some of my weapon slots now have 5 choices (with no duplicates!), and I find that certain combos of items work best together, so it'd be nice to be able to switch them all at once.

Is it possible to setup hotkeys to equip certain items, or even better, certain "sets" of items?

Just for clarity, what I'd like to do is be able to press a key and have all the equipment slots on the class I am playing get switched to particular items.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Valve finally added this as a first class feature a few patches ago, in the **[Manniversary Update](http://www.teamfortress.com/manniversary/thatsnotall.html)**:

You can now have up to **four** saved loadouts per class.

Comment: Believe it or not, 4 isn't enough Loadouts for me, at least not for Spy or Medic.

Comment: Yes, I agree, for lots of classes it isn't enough.  I bolded "four" so it's easy to pick out, not to emphasize it as being "a lot" or something.

Comment: Ok, you can have loadouts. But the question asked if there was a HOTKEY to switch loadouts?

Answer (score 2):

Good question.

**EDIT:** You are right, just tested and I failed. Valve removed `equip` cvar and it seems that is not possible anymore and that there are no other possibilities to get swap a set of items in one shot

<strike>I found a script example onf [FPSBanana](http://www.fpsbanana.com/scripts/4143) that describe the following steps (these are just some example for some classes):</strike>

In medic.cfg:

```
alias "main1"             "equip 5 0 0; bind F6 main2" //Equip Needlegun
alias "main2"             "equip 5 0 1; bind F6 main1" //Equip Blutsauger
```

And finally in autoexec.cfg (note: if you don't have this file, just open notepad put this in and then save as "autoexec.cfg" in "\tf\cfg"):

```
bind F6 "main2"
```

Comment: I haven't been able to test yet but the forum you linked to seems to state that this doesn't work anymore.   Do you know how to figure out which numbers map to which items?

Comment: You are right, just tested and I failed :( They remove "equip" cvar and it seems that is not possible anymore and that there are no other possibilities.

Comment: Add a note about the quick inventory key. It allows you to redefine your entire next loadout in 3 seconds while **still** walking towards the point.

Answer (score 2):

You can assign a key to allow you to switch your current weapon for one of the other weapons you have for the same loadout slot.  It doesn't save a set of weapons, but you can change your loadout in game and on the fly (you will have to visit a weapons locker or respawn for it to take effect though).  Simply select the weapon you want to change, hold the key you assigned, and then select the replacement weapon from the pop-up.

Comment: What key do you have to assign or what is the command you assign to a key to do this?

Comment: I don't think there is a default key-mapping, but you're looking for the "Open Character Loadout" and "Loadout Quickswitch".  The first will open the full loadout screen and the second will allow you do what I mentioned in my answer.