# Is there a way to quickly open the loadout menu?

Tags: team-fortress-2

Is there a quick way to directly jump to the loadout menu in Team Fortress?  Right now it seems you have to Press <kbd>,</kbd> to load the change class menu, then click <kbd>EDIT LOADOUT</kbd>, then select the class, and finally make my loadout selections.

This [similar question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/8817/is-it-possible-to-set-item-loadouts-to-a-hotkey-in-tf2) has no satisfactory answers, and is not asking the same thing.  I don't want to switch sets of weapons, I simply want to get directly to the loadout menu with less clicking.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yep, the <kbd>M</kbd> key will bring you right to the loadout screen for the class you are currently playing as.

Comment: I am annoyed that I haven't noticed that before.

Comment: Do you know the console command for opening loadout screen? I have rebinded all my keys and my 'm' key doesn't work like that now.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not too familiar with remapping keys other than by using the `Keyboard` tab of the settings.

Comment: @Air: The command seems to be `open_charinfo_direct`.